# Price Slider using jQuery UI working in Java environment to be optimised

Tags: javascript, optimization, jquery-ui

I am working on a price slider that is for a Java environment. It is working correctly but I would like to optimise it as much as possible. Any tips/advice?

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="range"></div>
    <div class="amount min-amount left"></div>
    <div class="amount max-amount right"></div>

    <form action="#" method="get" class="range-slider-form hidden">
        <input type="hidden" class="slider_q" name="q" value="${searchPageData}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="text" value="${searchPageData.freeTextSearch}" />
        <input type="hidden" class="slider_step" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" class="slider_min" name="minSel" value="${min}" /> 
        <input type="hidden" class="slider_max" name="maxSel" value="${max}" /> 
        <input type="hidden" class="price_min" name="minSlider" value="${minSlider}" /> 
        <input type="hidden" class="price_max" name="maxSlider" value="${maxSlider}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="resultsForPage" value="${rs}" />
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var slider_step = $(".slider_step"),
    price_min = $(".price_min"),
    price_max = $(".price_max"),
    slider_min = $(".slider_min"),
    slider_max = $(".slider_max");

$( ".range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: parseInt(price_min.val()),
    max: parseInt(price_max.val()),
    step: parseInt(slider_step.val()),
    values: [ parseInt(slider_min.val()), parseInt(slider_max.val()) ],
    slide: function(event, ui){
        //Sliding number
        $('.ui-slider-handle:eq(0) .price-range-min').html('&pound;' + ui.values[0]);
        $('.ui-slider-handle:eq(1) .price-range-max').html('&pound;' + ui.values[1]);
        $('.price-range-both').html('<i>&pound;' + ui.values[0] + ' - </i>&pound;' + ui.values[1] );

        if ( ui.values[0] == ui.values[1] ){
          $('.price-range-both i').css('display', 'none');
        } else{
          $('.price-range-both i').css('display', 'inline');
        }
        if (collision($('.price-range-min'), $('.price-range-max')) == true){
            $('.price-range-min, .price-range-max').css('opacity', '0');    
            $('.price-range-both').css('display', 'block');     
        } else{
            $('.price-range-min, .price-range-max').css('opacity', '1');    
            $('.price-range-both').css('display', 'none');      
        }
    },
    change: function(event, ui){
        /* update the values and submit the form */
        slider_min.val(ui.values[0]);
        slider_max.val(ui.values[1]);

        // getting search query string from html
        var q = $(".slider_q");

        // create string from array and add priceValue and prices in required format.
        var qrystr = q.val();
        if (qrystr.indexOf("priceValue") == -1){
            var r = qrystr+":priceValue:["+ui.values[0]+" TO "+ui.values[1]+"]";
        }
        else{
            var a = qrystr.split(":");
            a.splice(2,2);
            var r = a.join(":")+":priceValue:["+ui.values[0]+" TO "+ui.values[1]+"]";
        }
        q.val(r);
        // Submit the form
        $(".range-slider-form").submit();
    }
});

var minselected = parseInt($(".range").slider("values",0)),
    maxselected = parseInt($(".range").slider("values",1));

$('.ui-slider-range').append('<span class="price-range-both value"><i>&pound;' + minselected + ' - </i>' + maxselected + '</span>');
$('.ui-slider-handle:eq(0)').append('<span class="price-range-min value">&pound;' + minselected + '</span>');
$('.ui-slider-handle:eq(1)').append('<span class="price-range-max value">&pound;' + maxselected + '</span>');

//Collison of Min/Max Price
function collision($div1, $div2){
    var x1 = $div1.offset().left,
        w1 = 40,
        r1 = x1 + w1,
        x2 = $div2.offset().left,
        w2 = 40,
        r2 = x2 + w2;

    if (r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you put up a demo. I can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

From a once over;

- You are assigning a class to hidden input elements, that does not make sense. Assign an `id` instead, selection on `id` is much faster.
- `ui.values[0]` and `ui.values[1]` use magic sonstants, you should use named constants like `ui.values[SLIDER_MINIMUM]` and `ui.values[SLIDER_MAXIMUM]`
- Do not disemvowel your variable too much , `qrystr` <- That's too much
- You declare `var r` more than once in `change`, don't do that
- The variable name in `collision` are terrible
- The magic `40` should be a properly named constant
- The one line of comment for `collision` is pretty useless, moar comments are needed
- This :

  ```
  if (r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
  return true;`
  ```

  could be

  ```
  return !(r1 < x2 || x1 > r2)
  ```

All in all, I think this code requires some polishing, but the basics are okay.